# Should we still care about _escaped_fragment_ and alternate HTML generation for Single Page Applications?

Tags: javascript, google, seo

A few months ago I started a project, which will have two parts – business client overview panel (AngularJS SPA) and public front-end (dynamic HTML with progressive enchancements via XHR).

I'd really like to stop and throw away dynamic HTML and switch to AngularJS + API + static HTML combo (like in "panel") to avoid duplicate work in API resources and HTML templates.
As this content will be public and should be indexed, I'm lost on current Google Search [state](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html).

I'm not sure I wish to implement PhantomJS + nginx cache stack (to avoid DoS possibility via PhantomJS):

[image: SPA flowchart]

(I apologize for possibly unreadable font size.)

Have anyone of you deployed SPA-only site right now and can give any insights on how (if) Google indexes your site?

Comment: Google will now execute javascript when crawling your site ([see here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)). I'm not sure how well this works in practice, but this is great news for SPAs.

Comment: I recently wrote a new AngularJS project, and noticed that the binding brackets appear in google.. so I guess javascript support is not great yet.. I implemented phantomJS pre-rendering for my site.